# Render Set as Unordered List

Tags: apex

I want to make the set to display as Unorderlist.
So that it will display the values in an order that I have initialized.

Is there any way to achieve it?

```
Set<String> values = new Set<String>{'SZ','SA','EL','SP','DP'};
```

Answer (score 2):

[Sets](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/langCon_apex_collections_sets.htm) are unordered lists that don't contain duplicates. If you want to maintain the order, use a [List](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/langCon_apex_collections_lists.htm).

Answer (score 2):

Sets are un-ordered by their very nature. If you need an ordered list you should use a `List<String>` collection. If you need to ensure things are unique and other set features, then you can just get a list for rendering only by adding all of the set elements to a list:

```
public List<String> getOrderedList()
{
  List<String> orderedValues = new List<String>();
  orderedValues.addAll(values);
  orderedValues.sort();
  return orderedValues;
}
```

In your scenario you probably don't want the elements sorted alphabetically, so you'd be better off initialising the `list` first, and then adding all the list's elements to a set if that functionality is required.